# Email address as a Table in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm just wondering if it is OK to used the email address as a Table in SQL script? for example,

`abcd_activity@cdf.com up`

```
select distinct usr.user_name as USER_NAME, usr.id as USER_ID 
from abcd@cdf.com usr, abcd_activity@cdf.com -- <-----------------------
where usr.id = ua.id 
group by usr.name, usr.id;
```

My problem is that, I received the log file containing the error of the script and I noticed that the table used is email address. So, my assumption is that the caused of the error is in the table itself. Or, is it OK to use an email address as a lookup table in script?

Comment: Please Tag your really use tag. and what's the dbms version

Comment: Learn some database design.  Why would you want to use email address as a table name??  If you have 1 million emails, you'll have 1 million tables??

Comment: Always try to use ANSI JOIN standard. Your query still uses old JOIN syntax.

Comment: Why the GROUP BY when there are no aggregate functions involved. (Trying to do select distinct twice?=

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. Actually, I'm new in SQL and I am still learning from my side. The sample code above is from the errorlogs which I don't know where it is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

No, it is not all right to have a table name like  `abcd_activity@cdf.com`, for the simple reason that `.` and `@` are not allowed as table names.  So, any attempt to do:

```
from abcd_activity@cdf.com
```

is going to result in a syntax error.

SQL does allow you to escape table names.  You can get around this problem with one of these:

```
from "abcd_activity@cdf.com"
from `abcd_activity@cdf.com`
from [abcd_activity@cdf.com]
```

(which depends on your database).

More importantly, though, is that there is no sensible reason (that I can think of) to have a table represent separate emails.  Normally, `email` would be a *column* in a table, not a *table name*.

So, you would have tables like:

`Users` Table

```
userId    userName    email    . . .
```

And `UsersActivity` table:

```
userActivityId    userId    . . . .
```

`email` would be a column in `Users`, which you would look up using a `JOIN`.

Comment: Would also like to add that @ is reserved for use in accessing database links in databases like Oracle.

Comment: Thank you for your response.